# Corrupt vimrc file

Tags: vim, macvim, vimrc

I installed janus for my macvim (I am running Snow Leopard) and everytime I go to edit the ~/.vimrc file I get these errors:

```
Error detected while processing function Edit:
line    7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: ruby << RUBY
line    8:
E492: Not an editor command:   destination = File.expand_path(VIM.evaluate(%{sys
tem("dirname " . shellescape(a:file, 1))}))
line    9:
E488: Trailing characters:   pwd         = File.expand_path(Dir.pwd)
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command:   home        = pwd == File.expand_path("~")
line   12:
E121: Undefined variable: home
E15: Invalid expression: home || Regexp.new("^" + Regexp.escape(pwd)) !~ destina
tion
line   15:
command-t.vim requires Vim to be compiled with Ruby support
```

The changes I make work. But when I save and quit and reopen, the changes are no longer made and it is back to default.

Answer (score 1):

Get vim with ruby support. Compile yourself or get a binary.

```
$ wget https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/tarball/v7.3-53 
$ tar xzf  v7.3-53
$ cd b4winckler-macvim-730064c/
$ ./configure --enable-rubyinterp  
$ make
$ make install (or copy things manually to where you want...)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary since MacVim enables Ruby support by default.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to edit the file with `vim` or MacVim? If you're using the system's default command line `vim` (the one Apple provides), it probably lacks support for many things Janus relies on.

If you are using MacVim, then maybe you accidentally got a much older version? Since you say you're on Snow Leopard, you should go with the very latest [snapshot release](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases/download/snapshot-73/MacVim-snapshot-73-Mavericks.tbz) from the [downloads page on GitHub](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases).